# Type bytes memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type bytes calldata

Tags: contract-development, truffle, ethereumjs, hardhat, smart-lock

I'm using the openzeppelin library of TimelockController.sol. Specifically using the library's schedule function.

```
function schedule(
        address target,
        uint256 value,
        bytes calldata data,
        bytes32 predecessor,
        bytes32 salt,
        uint256 delay
    ) public virtual onlyRole(PROPOSER_ROLE) {
        bytes32 id = hashOperation(target, value, data, predecessor, salt);
        _schedule(id, delay);
        emit CallScheduled(id, 0, target, value, data, predecessor, delay);
    }
```

Now, see the parameters from [doc](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/governance#TimelockController-CallScheduled-bytes32-uint256-address-uint256-bytes-bytes32-uint256-).

**Target**: the address of the smart contract that the timelock should operate on.

**Value**: in Wei, that should be sent with the transaction. Most of the time this will be 0. Ether can be deposited before-end or passed along when executing the transaction.

**Data**: containing the encoded function selector and parameters of the call. This can be produced using a number of tools. For example, a maintenance operation granting role ROLE to ACCOUNT can be encoded using web3js as follows:

```
const data = timelock.contract.methods.grantRole(ROLE, ACCOUNT).encodeABI()
```

**Predecessor**: that specifies a dependency between operations. This dependency is optional. Use bytes32(0) if the operation does not have any dependency.

**Salt**: used to disambiguate two otherwise identical operations. This can be any random value.

By seeing all the things above, I implemented the schedule function like this...

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.10;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/governance/TimeLockController.sol";

interface Ierc20 {
    function mint(address to, uint amount) external; 
    function burn(uint amount) external;
}

contract TimeLock is TimelockController {

    function scheduleMintFuctionCall(address to, uint amount) public {

        address target = 0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3;
        bytes calldata data = abi.encodeWithSignature('Ierc20(target).mint(address, uint256)', to, amount);
        uint256 value = 10000000;
        bytes32 salt = keccak256("MY_SALT");
        uint256 delay = block.timestamp + 3 minutes;
        schedule(target, value, data, bytes32(0), salt, delay);
        
    }

}
```

Now, I want to schedule my deployed erc20 function which is at the address `0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3` and that's why I feed this address as the target parameter of the function(the address of the smart contract that the timelock should operate on.)

I'm having a problem at

```
bytes calldata data = abi.encodeWithSignature('Ierc20(target).mint(address, uint256)', to, amount);
```

here I'm getting the error

```
Type bytes memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type bytes calldata.
```

before this, I tried to do it as

`bytes calldata data = abi.encode/Packed(Ierc20(target).mint(address, uint256))` but getting almost same errors.

After this I tried

```
bytes4 FUNC_SELECTOR = bytes4(keccak256('Ierc20(target).mint(address, uint256)'));
bytes calldata data = abi.encodeWithSelector(FUNC_SELECTOR, to, amount);
```

but same `Type bytes memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type bytes calldata.` error.

Anyone, please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`calldata` represents the data of the (internal) transaction. This data cannot be adjusted inside a call, therefore you cannot write into `calldata`.

There are two ways to go ahead with this:

- Have the data be provided by the sender that calls your method and define it there as a `calldata` parameter.
- Perform an internal transaction to the `schedule` method (which is slightly more expensive). This can be done by using `this.schedule(...)`. Note: this will only work if the `schedule` function is marked as `public` or `external` (which is the case in your example).

For your example:

```js
function scheduleMintFuctionCall(address to, uint amount) public {
  address target = 0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3;
  bytes memory data = abi.encodeWithSignature('Ierc20(target).mint(address, uint256)', to, amount);
  uint256 value = 10000000;
  bytes32 salt = keccak256("MY_SALT");
  uint256 delay = block.timestamp + 3 minutes;
  this.schedule(target, value, data, bytes32(0), salt, delay);
}
```